# MS-organization-access asking for Credentials on window 10. It says confirm the certificate to access website

Tags: ssl, window

I have a website host on IIS 10 and installed wild card SSL. The website is working fine on all other machines and on the server as well. When i access it on my window 10 machine, it is asking to confirm the security certificate and credentials. If i press the ok button the site went to 403 Forbidden error.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue was related to the server. My Hosting provider has made the following changes at IIS.

> IIS -> Websites -> Go to website -> SSL settings
>
> client certificate to ignore